# Horror ghost movie with people trapped in a house

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I watched this movie as a child, and I would like to watch it again.

These people are trapped in a house and there is a box full of heads that was supposed to stay buried so the spirits wouldn’t disturb the house. There is a ghost lady thing who is playing the piano in a white dress and her fingers are bleeding onto the piano keys. Then whenever she gets up, her shoes are black pointed toe boots that drag the floor as she floats across the room.

The windows and doors are all locked shut so the people cannot get out of the house. There are ghost or entities in the house that the people cannot see and a lady is getting her neck cut by an entity with glass and all her friends can see is glass cutting her throat. And the ghost lady is in the bathroom on the roof looking down on the other people are trying to escape.

Comment: "I watched this movie as a child" -> Can you specify the approximate year/decade?  We don't know when you were a child.

Comment: Parts of this remind me off the House on Haunted Hill remake.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_(1977_film)?

Answer (score 4):

No, not *House*; this is much more recent (and less bizarre). You're looking for [The Gravedancers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435653/) from 2005 with Clare Kramer (from *Buffy*) and Dominic Purcell (from *Prison Break*). Everything you mentioned is in there. IMDb synopsis:

> After a night of drunken exploits [i.e. dancing on graves], Allison, Harris, and Kira are chased and terrorized by the ghosts of a child pyromaniac, an ax murderer, and a rapist.

- After being haunted by the dead people's ghosts, they're eventually shut in a house and discover that one of them kept the dead people's skulls in a chest and that they have to rebury them;
- One of the ghosts is a lady dressed in a white gown who plays the piano at one point as she's all drenched in blood (she was once a piano teacher IIRC);
- At some point, people watch in horror as a ghost (which they can't see) slits a woman's throat with a shard of glass - you can actually watch the scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxQoxgtH4B0) *(WARNING: GRAPHIC)*;
- Everything else is in there too; the ghost lady on the roof, and her feet dragging on the floor as she floats - which you can see briefly near the end of the trailer:

*[P.S. As a bonus, [here's a featurette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQB9dYcoNnc) about the making of these ghouls, including the lady in white]*

Answer (score 2):

Although it does not match in all respects, the Japanese film *House* (1977) does fit some particulars.  It includes a severed head that, when it is released, triggers other supernatural occurrences around the house.  There are the usual sealed exits that keep the seven visiting young women inside.  And, most notably, there is a scene where one of the girls, dressed in white, [plays the piano with bloody fingers](https://vimeo.com/68372410).

While the film has a [Criterion Collection release](https://www.criterion.com/films/27523-house), it is, in my opinion, a terrible film, potentially enjoyable only as "so bad it's good."  This trailer, in addition to showing some of the other plot points listed above, gives a pretty accurate depiction of how amateurish the production is.

Comment: I'll agree that it matches on several points (and I'm kicking myself that I didn't follow up on it showing up among my search results) but I will disagree that it's a terrible film. It does have some very cheesy special effects, but the story is decent and it's good in a surreal sort of way.